# loading data that the size isnt determined in highchart

Tags: javascript, csv

Ok, I just started learning JavaScript, and Highchart, and I need some help from someone who can 
nudge me to the right direction.

So, I am basically displaying a data on pie chart in highchart api.

And the datas that I get is in csv form.

Once I get the datas to a array in javascript, i do not know what i have to do next.

since the size of the data is not determined, 
i dont know how i should code the data input part.

the data input part is

```
series: [{
                            type: 'pie',
                            name: 'Occurence',
                            point: {
                                events:
                                {
                                    click: function(event)
                                    {
                                        location.href = this.options.url;
                                        event.preventDefault();
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            data: [
                                ['Robbery',1900],
                                ['Assult',4693],
                                ['Non_criminal',6516],
                                { 
                                    name:'Larceny/Theft',
                                    y: 14827,
                                    sliced : true,
                                    selected : true

                                }
                            ]
                        }]
```

Something llike this.

I can not find a way of putting datas when the size of the data is not defined.

So for the above example, the size of the data would be 4.

Is there any way of approaching this issue?

Would appreciate any input from you genius stackoverflow members!

Comment: Hmm, the data that you provided seems to be JSON file, not CSV... :)

Comment: oh, well that is how the datas are given in highchart API. but oh well i dont care if it is in json. ;)